# Class events don't fire in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events

In an ASP.NET Web application, events of a Class don't fire at all.

It does not produce any error, but doesn't work either.

What I've tried so far:

- Put the Class code in the same aspx codefile, didn't work
- Used the AddHandler to handle the event right after creating a new
  instance - didn't work
- Changed AutoEvenFireup="true" in the top of
  aspx page, didn't work
- Added Asynch="true" to aspx page, didn't
  work

Here is the simplest example:

testEvent.aspx:

```
Public Class testEvent
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public WithEvents TestClass As MyClassWithEvents

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        TestClass = New MyClassWithEvents


    End Sub

    Private Sub TestClass_SimpleEvent(txt As String) Handles TestClass.SimpleEvent

        Response.Write("Event fired from class: " + txt + "<br />")

    End Sub


End Class
```

MyClassWithEvents.vb:

```
Public Class MyClassWithEvents

    Public Event SimpleEvent(txt As String)

    Public Sub New()

        RaiseEvent SimpleEvent("Sub New() in Class")
        SomeMethod()

    End Sub

    Public Sub SomeMethod()

        RaiseEvent SimpleEvent("SomeMethod() called in Class")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

When I call `SomeMethod()` in the `PreRender` event:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Me.TestClass.SomeMethod()
End Sub
```

It works fine. Must be too early in the lifecycle in `Load` for the events to fire.